# How do remove unwanted linefeed charachter from file-download in Laravel Nova?

Tags: php, laravel, download, laravel-nova, linefeed

In a Laravel Nova application i've got a strange issue: Whenever i try to download a file i have a linefeed char on the first line (0A, an empty line). This corrupts images, zip-files and so on. But what is causing this?

I've tried/checked:

1. Check all php files on closing tags (there are none)
2. Original file on hdd **does not** have this extra linefeed when it's created
3. Checked every php file since last release for correct UTF-8 encoding
4. Copied composer.lock from live server and installed everything again
5. Ran composer dump, php artisan cache:clear, php artisan clear-compiled
6. Checked all code changes since the last release (where there was no issue)
7. Tried Chrome and Firefox

Here's some Laravel Nova code that produced this error:

```
return Fields\Image::make(__('Image')), 'imageStorage')
        ->rules('image', "dimensions:max_width={$image_max_width},max_height={$image_max_height}")
        ->squared()
        ->disk(Enums\StorageDisk::APP_PUBLIC_DISTRIBUTORS)
        ->path(DistributorPath::products($distributorId))
        ->deletable(false)
        ->prunable()
        ->onlyOnForms();
```

First charachter is always 0A.

So, how do i find the cause? Any tips or strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the linebreak was hiding in a routes file.

This mistake was made almost a year ago and never surfaced until now, because it was no issue in any of the output the application created (html / xml). Started to be a problem when I tried to output binary files (zip / images).

So how did i find this bug? `die('find bug!');`

For anyone in the future:

- Start at index.php
- Place `die('find bug!');` at one place and test.
- Don't be afraid to place it in vendor or library code.
- No linebreak? Remove `die('find bug!');` and place it in the next call.
- Found the linebreak? So now you now the linebreak is somewhere inbetween.
- Zoom in and find it!